# ESP after SEH Exception with same program on different computers

Tags: stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, exploit, seh

Below are a few articles that exploit different programs by using ESP after the SEH exception to POPAD back to a controllable part of the stack.  The other article demonstrates stack pivoting finding suitable code inside a loaded module to pivot the stack to the desired location.  These exploits rely on the ESP location after the SEH exception to be the same every time on every computer with the same OS in order to produce a reliable exploit.  Otherwise 38 POPAD's or a particular ROP might not land inside your buffer.

My question:  3 Windows 10 64bit english fully updated VM's, no DEP.  The same version of a test program installed on all 3.  This program has No Rebase, No SafeSEH, No ASLR, not NX Compatible.  After an SEH exception, the distance from ESP to the start of the controllable buffer on the stack is different on all 3 operating systems. Why am I not able to reproduce the results of these exploits with my VM's?

PUSHAD:

www.mattandreko.com/2013/04/06/buffer-overflow-in-hexchat-294/

ROP Stack Pivot:

thesprawl.org/research/corelan-tutorial-10-exercise-solution/#pivoting-to-the-stack

Comment: Look for a pointer to the buffer at a fixed distance from esp. Pop pop ret which is the most common way to return to stack from an SEH overwrite works because there is a pointer to the buffer two dwords down from esp. Otherwise you would need to provide some more details.

Comment: @wireghoul Yeah, I think that's what I was missing.  Thank you.